# VueJS - Go directly to children route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've made a dashboard with vuejs.
My problem is that i want to go directly to a route "dashboard/my-profile".
This route is a children of another :

```
{
    path: '/dashboard', 
    name: 'dashboard',          
    components: { default:Dashboard },      
    children: [ 
            {
                path: 'my-profile', 
                name: 'show_profile', 
                components: {
                    subview: Profile
                }           
            }
        ]
}
```

When i try to directly go to 'dashboard/my-profile' it load good but immediately redirect to 'dashboard' his parent
Do you have any idea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not defined router-view for the `Profile`:

```
<router-view></router-view><!-- Default: Dashboard -->
<router-view name="subview"></router-view><!-- Profile -->
```